# contents of components not updating on frontend vue.js in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vue-component

I have a component when i change the content of that component it does not reflect on the browser, for that i'm running

```
npm update
```

but i'm getting following error:

> npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME npm ERR! Invalid package name
> "itor/ckeditor5-build-clas@ckedsic": name can only contain
> URL-friendly characters

Answer (score 0):

PLease check your package.json. I think you just make a mistake in the line where you add the "itor/ckeditor5-build-clas@ckedsic" package.